# Not able to open the excel file downloaded from sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba

I am downloading excel file using below VBA code , but after downloading when try to open the file getting the error - excel cannot open the file because the file format is invalid .." This problem is only with files downloaded using below code,

```
Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate
    Dim myURL As String
    myURL = Cells(2, 6).Value2
    Debug.Print myURL
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
    WinHttpReq.Send
    Debug.Print WinHttpReq.Status
    myURL = WinHttpReq.responseBody
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile folderPath & "\REPORT\Data.xlsm", 2
       
        oStream.Close
        MsgBox "File Download Successful"
        downloadFile = 1

    Else
        MsgBox "File Download Failed"
        downloadeFile = 0

    End If
```

Comment: When you download a macro-enabled file, you have to "unblock" it first. Right click on it and select properties. This is intentional meant to prevent malicious code from being downloaded and run unknowingly.

Comment: Hi , Thanks brax let me check and unblock and let u know

Comment: I unblocked , but same error .

Comment: Excel cannot open the file, because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and the file extension matches the format of the file. @brax

Comment: @braX could you please help me on this

Comment: You already tried my idea.

Comment: Yeah anything else there?

Comment: Also used the ptrsafe function URLDownload to file concepts it doesnt returns 0 . It returns -2317786 like this.

Comment: What about `Workbook.Open(myURL)` ?

Comment: Its a internal URL , but  format is    https://mysharepoint/path/name.xlsm